# Configure DB Connection Pooling - Axis2 webservice

Tags: oracle, tomcat, connection-pooling, apache-axis

I'd like to know how to modify the server.xml file so all my webservices built on axis2 can talk to the DB using Connection Pooling. Each webservice has a different data source, one points to one instance of the DB and the other to another DB server. How do I specify the context that should be used by each service?

Thanks in advance,
Pojo

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use connection pool in your project , Ensure that you have the following code set up for the Tomcat connection pooling to work in context.xml file:

1)Create file with name "context.xml" if it's not exist under directory "WebContent/META-INF/context.xml" with the following content:

For My Project , Please modify it with appropriate value :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Context path="/dbcp" docBase="dbcp">  
    <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="30" maxActive="80"   
        maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="sontn" password="nhantien"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/group8"   useUnicode="true"
        characterEncoding="utf-8" characterSetResults="utf8"/>
</Context>
```

Or you can copy file : context.xml into directory "$Catalian\webapps\axis2\META-INF"

How can you get connection pool?

In your webservice method : create method getConnection() with following content:

```
public Connection getConnection() {   
    Connection connection = null;   
    try {
        Context envCtx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
        connection = ds.getConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Connection error: " + e.getMessage());   
    }
    return connection; 
}
```

Thanks